# how to change the account password expiration date in Linux

Tags: password

I am confused about the password expiration date in Linux. Looks like chage command -e changes the account expiration date not the password expiration date. They are totally different. I can not find any command that can be used to change the password expiration date. They all change the user expiration date. is there any way to do this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `chage -M`. For example, to set 90 days as the maximum before password expiry enter `sudo chage -M 90 <username>`.

EDIT: To set an exact expiration date you need to figure out how many days that are between the Last password change date (see `chage -l`) and your desired password expiration date and then use that number in `chage -M`.